# How to read a csv file with encoding ISO-8859-15 which is inside a zip file and without unzipping it in R language

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding, zip, unzip

I have some zip files with a lot of .csv files inside encoded as ISO-8859-15 and with special characters (like " ã ") and I would like to read them with the special characters without unzipping them (for example with `unz`) so that I wouldn't lose time in the process nor space in my hard-drive. With time, I will have to download more of those zip files, so it's not a one time process. The problem is that setting `encoding = "ISO-8859-15"` is not working. All special characters are not being read properly ("ã" will be read as "\xe3").

For reproduction, you can save a text file named `test.txt` written `testãóçáà` in it (remember to choose the proper encoding when saving it: `Western (ISO-8859-15)`) and compress it in a zip file named `test.zip`.

Outside the zip file, I can read it with the functions `read.csv`and `readLines` without problem:

```
file_txt <- "test.txt"

readLines(file(file_txt,encoding = "ISO-8859-15"))           # option 1
read.csv(file_txt,fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-15",header = F)   # option 2
read.csv(file(file_txt,encoding = "ISO-8859-15"),header = F) # option 3
```

and the output will be `"testãóçáà"` (in a vector and in a dataframe). Without setting the encoding, the output will be `"test\xe3\xf3\xe7\xe1\xe0"`

As far as I know, `unz` is analogous to `file`, and it can read a file inside a zip file without unzipping it (and saving the file in my hard-drive), but the following doesn't work properly:

```
file_txt <- "test.txt"
file_zip <- "test.zip"


readLines(unz(file_zip, file_txt,encoding = "ISO-8859-15"))           # option 1
read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt,encoding = "ISO-8859-15"),header = F) # option 2
```

In both cases, the output is also `"test\xe3\xf3\xe7\xe1\xe0"`, as if the `encoding` was not being used. Maybe it is a problem with the `unz` function?

**Edit:**
Based on comments, the following alternatives didn't work as well:

```
# for the zipped file
read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt), encoding = "ISO-8859-15")
read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt), fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-15")
# Analogies for the unzipped file also don't work
read.csv(file(file_txt),header = F, encoding = "ISO-8859-15")
read.csv(file(file_txt),header = F, fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-15")
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping the encoding as an argument to read.csv instead of to unz?  `read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt), encoding = "ISO-8859-15")`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thanks for your reply. Yes, I tried both `read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt), encoding = "ISO-8859-15")` and `read.csv(unz(file_zip, file_txt), fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-15")` but they didn't work as well. In this case, their analogous when reading the unzipped file also don't work (`read.csv(file(file_txt),header = F, fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-15")`)

Comment: I'm afraid that, at least on windows, the encoding of `unz` and `gzcon` does not work and reading from a unz stream ignores further encoding (source on iconv darkly says [/* not yet */](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/dounzip.c#L437)). I suggest to use  `unzip` in a tmp file (use `tempdir()` or `tempfile()`) as i think it is also faster despite not being a pipe, because it is native.

Comment: I see, thanks @RicVillalba! I'm on Linux, so it seems a problem for both operational systems. I'll try to use temp-files as workaround as you suggested.